# Count XML element over multiple documents within PHP

Tags: php, xml, foreach, count

I have multiple XML documents which contain output from an API - this output is support tickets from our ticketing system. I am trying to count tickets where the status is set to a particular status.

The XML output looks like below (though with a lot more request elements across 7 documents).

```
<response uri="/api/xml/getRequestsByView">
<result>
    <status>Success</status>
    <statuscode>200</statuscode>
    <requests>
        <request>
            <form name="requestID">12345</form>
            <form name="userTimeFormat">dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm:ss</form>
            <form name="contact">Name</form>
            <form name="status">Open</form>
            <form name="statusID">1</form>
            <form name="priority">P3 Minor</form>
            <form name="supportRep"/>
            <form name="supportRepCostPerHour">0.00</form>
            <form name="createdTime">20 Jun 2017, 08:22:00</form>
            <form name="updatedTime">20 Jun 2017, 08:23:11</form>
            <form name="dueByTime"/>
            <form name="isOverDue">false</form>
            <form name="accountID"/>
            <form name="account"/>
            <form name="subject">Subject Name</form>
        </request>
        <request>
            <form name="requestID">12346</form>
            <form name="userTimeFormat">dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm:ss</form>
            <form name="contact">Contact Name</form>
            <form name="status">Open</form>
            <form name="statusID">1</form>
            <form name="priority">P3 Minor</form>
            <form name="supportRep"/>
            <form name="supportRepCostPerHour">0.00</form>
            <form name="createdTime">20 Jun 2017, 08:21:58</form>
            <form name="updatedTime">20 Jun 2017, 08:23:10</form>
            <form name="dueByTime"/>
            <form name="isOverDue">false</form>
            <form name="accountID"/>
            <form name="account"/>
            <form name="subject">Subject Name</form>
        </request>
    </requests>
</result>
```

So far, I created the below function - the output I get from the below is "1440". It should work, as when I replaced the count element to echo each match, the output displayed the status of each ticket that had a matching status - just the counting element doesn't appear to function as desired.

```
function countPriority($status){
    $files = array("includes/xml-1.xml","includes/xml-2.xml","includes/xml-3.xml","includes/xml-4.xml","includes/xml-5.xml","includes/xml-6.xml","includes/xml-7.xml");
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($files as $url) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
        foreach ($xml->result->requests->request as $request){
            if ($request->form['3'] == $status){
                $count+= count($request);
            }
        }
        return $count;
    }
}
```

I am a complete novice when it comes to PHP/Coding, so any suggestions or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Move `return` out of `foreach`

Comment: Moved - thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have an error here: `$count+= count($request);`. If you're just trying to count how many tickets with certain status are, then you simply need to increase counter by one, like `$count++;`. Instead what you're doing is increasing the value of `$count` by the amount of elements in each `$request`.

Also, as pointed out in the comments, you should move `return` statement out of your `foreach` loop, because otherwise your method only loops through first file in the array.

So your method should look like this:

```
function countPriority($status){
    $files = array("includes/xml-1.xml","includes/xml-2.xml","includes/xml-3.xml","includes/xml-4.xml","includes/xml-5.xml","includes/xml-6.xml","includes/xml-7.xml");
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($files as $url) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
        foreach ($xml->result->requests->request as $request){
            if ($request->form['3'] == $status){
                $count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist!